How to type Very Large font size (to be used for title of the chapter)?
I am typing  a research presentation in LATEX.
For sections inside the chapter I use the code \title{ \Large {\underline{Section 6} Proof }}
I want a more Larger font for chapter name. What is the code that I should use? Can I use the \title{ \VeryLarge {\underline{Section 6} Proof of Theorem 2}}\\ or not? If not then what code I should use?
To work the \binom code I need to type \usepackage{amsmath}.
What code is needed to make the \title{ \Large {\underline{Section 6} Proof }}\\ work?
Edit1: This is my document structure.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\title{test}
$\title{ \Large {\underline{Section 6} Proof of Theorem 2}}$$\\
$\title{ \VeryLarge {\underline{Section 6} Proof of Theorem 2}}$$\\
\date{June 2024}
\bar{J}
\begin{document}
$\Mycomb [n]{r}$
$\tilde{H}$
$\dbinom{n}{k}$
$d_n^k$
$t^3_5$
\section{Introduction}
\underline{ Lemma 4}
\end{document}


You should probably search this site for similar questions first. There should be lots of answers where you find \fontsize{80}{95}\selectfont for example.

Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

One one the basic concepts of latex is to separate layout and content. You should almost never need to manually add formatting instructions in macros like \title. Instead better adjust the layout of the title (how to do that will depend on a MWE)

Please do reveal more information about the structure of your document. In particular, which document class you employ? And why do you (apparently) use title instead of \section to generate a section-level header?

Setting the font size of secion-level headers should be entirely independent of whether or not the amsmath package gets loaded. If your document somehow links these two distinct issues, something must be badly messed up in your document structure.

@Mico So, for Section I should add section? Well I have now used \title for about 20 sections and is there a way that I work this out using \section only?

You should only use \title once. The $ and $$ around it in the preamble will cause errors, as well as the \bar{J} before the document starts.

@Avenger - Please do yourself a huge favor and take some time to study any basic introduction to LaTeX. (E.g., check out the document The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX.) That way, you'll acquire relevant information much more quickly and more systematically than by stumbling around in a fairly uncontrolled manner from pitfall to pitfall.

For sure, LaTeX must burn and crash when it encounters \VeryLarge... Does encountering error messages ever give you pause? Incidentally, the title of your query mentions "chapter", whereas the body of your query appears to be concerned with section-level entries, not chapter-level entries. But then, you also appear to be using the article document class -- which doesn't even feature a \chapter directive. This is all needlessly confusing, isn't it?

Incidentally, since you employ the amssymb package, there can be absolutely not justfication, or excuse, for loading latexsym as well.

My apologies for providing a bad link in my earlier comment. The corrected link is this. In particular, do please read chapter 1, "LaTeX Basics"; chapter 2, "Real World LaTeX"; and chapter 3, "Typesetting Mathematical Formulae".

@Mico Yes, thanks I am doing it.

@Mico Thank you very much for your advice. I really needed it!!

You could use the titling package to adjust the layout of the title:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}% scaleable font

\usepackage{titling}% customise maketitle
\pretitle{\begin{center}\fontsize{36}{40}\selectfont}

\title{\underline{Section 6} Proof of Theorem 2}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}


